# Simple server handling routes and giving error nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, routes

I'm trying to write a simple server using nodejs and have the server ship back different queries and/or custom headers/responses based on the routes.  However, in the getUsers() function the error keeps getting hit and printing the 'Error querying' to the console instead of printing the email rows.  I know the server is connected fine, because I can return a query when I just use the db and return a query with createConnection only using the second example.  Any help spotting the error is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

What I'm trying to get done:

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var url = require('url');
var util = require('util');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "*********",
  user     : "*********",
  password : "*********",
  port     : '****',
  database : '*********' 
});

db.connect(function(err) {
  console.log('connected');
   if (err)
        console.error('Error connecting to db' + err.stack);
});

function getUsers() {
db.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err)
    // changed console.error('Error querying');
    console.error(err);
  if (rows)
    console.log('Rows not null');
  for (var i in rows) {
    console.log(rows[i].email)
  }
});
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.url); 
  if (req.url == '/signup') {
    console.log("User signing up");
  } else if (req.url == '/signin') {
    console.log("User signing in");
  } else if (req.url == '/new') {
    console.log("User request new game");
getUsers();
  }
  //res.writeHead(200);
  //res.end('Hello Http');
});

server.listen(3000);

// changed and commented out db.end();
```

What does work with querying the db:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "********",
  user     : "********",
  password : "********",
  port     : '****',
  database : '********' 
});

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM users';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log('Users: ', rows[i].email);
        }
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: Instead of `'Error querying'`, why not pass the error to `console.error()` so you know what the problem is. That's what it's there for.

Comment: ^ agreed, you're the cause of the lack of debugging output here. log the error, not that there is simply an error

Comment: when I changed the line to console.error(), nothing was output.  Also, the console.log for the rows doesn't get hit suggesting there was a problem with the query, and I know there isn't a problem because I can use the second method and return a query to the console.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think when @BenFortune said to pass the error he meant write this: `console.error(err)`.

Comment: Yes, this helped.  The error was:     { [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }  Once, I commented out the     db.end();  everything was working fine.  Thanks for the help.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The code has been updated with the changes, and the problem was I was closing the database.  After changing the error logs as was suggested in the comments, this was the error received.

```
{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }
```

I then commented out the

```
db.end()
```

and the queries were returned fine.

Thanks for the help.